# "to not be" Vs. "to not being"

Tags: meaning-in-context

What's the difference between the two following sentences?

> a) I came by subway in order to not **be** late.
>
> b) I came by subway in order to not **being** late.

For my non native English speaker ears, both sound natural. Isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

"in order to not being" is ungrammatical, because "in order to" always takes the plain form of the verb. So "in order to not be late" is correct.

English treats the subway (or any vehicle) as a *means* of travel, not a tool, so the preposition is *by*, not *with*: "I came by subway" (or "by the subway", if you want to specify a particular subway, but that's less common).

So the sentence should be "I came by subway in order to not be late." (It could also be simplified to "I came by subway to not be late.")

Comment: Good answer, is it right to say: i came by subway **so that I am not being late**?

Comment: "I am not being late" doesn't work; it should be just "I am not late". (*be* and *have* are special.) But this clause describes an intended goal, not a fact, so it would normally be subjunctive: "so [that] I would not be late".

Comment: @Cardinal Note that you would say *I came by subway in order* **to avoid** ***being*** *late.* In that construction, it's *be* that's ungrammatical, if preceded by *to avoid*.